# How do I find my Google Adsense API "parent" account?

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, google-api, adsense, adsense-api

I am trying to set up the Google Adsense API for a project I am working on and have started playing around with the [Google OAuth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). Some of the commands in the list they provide reference a "parent" account.

Example:
`GET https://adsense.googleapis.com/v2/{parent=accounts/*}/payments`

I am struggling to find what that "parent" parameter is referring to. I imagine that is the account that I used when setting up Google Adsense, but I can't figure out what I need to input.
I feel like if I knew how to find that parent ID or Name I could use that and make the requests I need. I have Google Cloud Platform set up and have the Google Adsense API enabled in my test project.

I can call `GET https://adsense.googleapis.com/v2/accounts` and it returns my payment accounts successfully so I know that I have it authenticating to some extent.

When I attempt a request with an incorrect parent ID/Name I get the following:

(In this example I tried using "admin" for my parent ID/Name

```
GET /v2/admin/payments HTTP/1.1
Host: adsense.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer <BEARER-TOKEN>
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-length: 1578
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Server: ESF
Date: Wed, 06 Dec 2023 06:20:21 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>Thatâs an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v2/admin/payments</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>Thatâs all we know.</ins>
```

I have attempted to build a console App to send the request for me using my clientID and clientSecret along with the email address for the account I used to setup the Google Adsense API. The response I get when I attempt to use that account looks like this:

```
The service adsense has thrown an exception.
HttpStatusCode is Forbidden.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The caller does not have permission [403]
Errors [
    Message[The caller does not have permission] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]

Google.GoogleApiException: The service adsense has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The caller does not have permission
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.ExecuteAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion.SerilogIngestionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I answered my own question. The account ID was in the url for the Google Adsense console.

I got it from here: https://www.google.com/adsense/new/u/0/pub-1234567890/myads/units

I then used that ID for my requests in this format: `accounts/pub-1234567890`

Worked like a charm!